# Generalisation of Fermat's Little Theorem in Function Fields

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, function-fields

There is a well-known generalisation of Fermat's Little Theorem as for any $a\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$ we have $$\sum_{d\mid n} \mu(n/d) a^d\equiv 0\pmod n.$$ where $\mu$ is the Möbius function. I wonder if this formula still holds in function fields. Say $F$ be a finite field and $F[x]$ be the polynomial ring over $F$. Then $F[x]$ is an Unique Factorisation Domain. Then we can define $\mu$ ($F[x]$ is an Euclidean Domain so primes and irreducibles are same). What I wonder is the following formula holds and is it easy to see if it does? 
Let $f\in F[x]$ where $F$ is a finite field. Then $$\sum_{d\mid f} \mu(f/d)a^{|d|}\equiv 0 \pmod f$$ where $|d|=|F[x]/\langle d\rangle|$.

Comment: This is equivalent to the question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1824797 (because $\mu\left(P\right)=\varphi\left(P\right)$ in $F$ for every $P\left[x\right]$), which has now been answered.