# Show that $\sum_{d\mid f} \varphi(f/d) a^{|d|} \equiv 0 \pmod f$

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, polynomials, algebraic-number-theory

This equation is correct when $f$ and $a$ are any integers. I want to show that this holds for $f,a\in K[x]$ where $K$ is any finite field.

In the equation $\varphi(f)$ is defined as $|(K[x]/(f))^\times|$, the number of units in the quotient ring and $|d|$ defined as $|K[x]/(d)|$, the number of elements in the quotient ring.

I tried many ways to prove this equation but I only know the proof of the integer case using group theoretic counting arguments and it is not easy to use them for polynomials.

Edit : The proof for integers is based on the Polya counting. If you have a finite group $G$, acting on a finite set $\Omega$ and if $a$ is any integer, we have $\sum_{g\in G} a^{c(g)}\equiv 0 \pmod{|G|}$ where $c(g)$ is the number of orbits of the action of $\langle g\rangle$ on $\Omega$. (This fact follows easily from simple orbit counting formula and Polya counting)

If we take $G$ as the cyclic group of order $n$ in this argument and let it act on itself via right multiplication, then for any $d$ dividing $n$, we have $\varphi(n/d)$ distinct elements of order $n/d$ and the subgroup generated by these elements form exactly $d$ different orbits on $G$ (cosets of the subgroup which is generated by them). Thus the result follows.

It is not clear to me how to generalise this fact to polynomials since group theoretic counting arguments hold only for integers as I know.

Comment: I suspect that this could be provable using Theorem 2.12 in my draft http://web.mit.edu/~darij/www/algebra/carlitz-status-v3.pdf , and that you might have some interest in this draft (and the whole theory of Carlitz polynomials) if you like this kind of $\mathbb{F}_q$-analogues of number-theoretical results. But let me see if I can say anything more concrete.

Comment: By the way, if I correctly understand your definition of $\varphi\left(f\right)$, then it is the same as what I call $\varphi\left(f\right)$ in my draft, and so is congruent to what you call $\mu\left(f\right)$ modulo the characteristic of $K$. Hence, your question is equivalent to your question at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1621572/generalisation-of-fermats-little-theorem-in-function-fields .

Comment: Well, in that question $\mu(f)$ is the Möbius function and here it is the totient function. I just checked the paper you sent me and it looks like it gives the generalisation thet I was looking for. Thanks for sending me, I'll read it and write back.

Comment: The thing is that your $\mu\left(f\right)$ and $\varphi\left(f\right)$ are congruent modulo the characteristic of $K$, and so become equal when multiplied with anything in $K$. Glad you found the draft of use, though I have to warn that it doesn't contain proofs for any of the interesting results yet.

Comment: Oh I didn't know that, thanks for the information.

Comment: Update to my first comment above: The file http://web.mit.edu/~darij/www/algebra/carlitz-status-v3.pdf has now been moved to http://web.mit.edu/~darij/www/algebra/schur-pre.pdf , and its Theorem 2.12 has been renumbered as Theorem 2.13. And yes, my suspicion was right (see the answer below).

Answer (score 0):

I have finally written up a proof. See Corollary 3.78 in my report [*Do the symmetric functions have a function-field analogue?*](http://www.cip.ifi.lmu.de/~grinberg/algebra/schur-ore.pdf). (Caution: The numbering will probably change several times. See [the PDF compiled the 4th of November 2016](https://github.com/darijgr/schur-ore/releases/tag/2016-11-04) for a frozen version whose numbering definitely agrees with my post here.)

Most of my report (which is long, and for all the bad reasons) is off-topic to your question, since the proof (well, the second proof) of Corollary 3.78 is mostly self-contained. All you need to read (I think) are §1.1, §1.2, §3.14, and the second proof of Corollary 3.78. I suspect that you know most of §3.14 already, but I could not locate the proofs in the literature, so I found it easier to write them down.